# What is a metric function and how to prove that a function is following the triangle inequality axiom?

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

I have a distance functions $d(x,y)=1/|x-y| $ and $d(x,y) = 0$ when $x = y$ 
I am trying to prove that it is metrics on $\mathbb R$,

So, is this function is a metric?

Thank you

Comment: question updated I forget to add $d(x,y) = 0$ when $x = y$

Answer (score 4):

The triangle inequality
$$
d(x,z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)
$$
is trivially satisfied if any two of $x, y, z$ are equal. For pairwise
different $x, y, z \in \Bbb R$ one has to show that
$$
\frac{1}{|x-z|} \le \frac{1}{|x-y|} + \frac{1}{|y-z|}
$$
This inequality does not change if $x, y, z$ are translated or
scaled by the same amount, so we can assume that $x=0, z=1$, and
have to show that
$$
1 \le \frac{1}{|y|} + \frac{1}{|1-y|}
\Longleftrightarrow |y(1-y)| \le |y| + |1-y|
$$
for $y \ne 0, 1$.

But the left-hand side of the last inequality grows quadratically in
$y$ while the right-hand side grows only linearly, so that cannot be true
generally, and a counter-example can be found be choosing $y$ 
large enough.

For example, the last inequality does not hold for $y=3$, which shows
that $d$ does **not satisfy the triangle inequality:**
$$
d(0, 3) + d(3, 1) = \frac 13 + \frac 12 < 1 = d(0, 1)
$$
and therefore is **not a metric.**

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that it satisfies the 3 metric space axioms.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure about the triangle inequality axiom

Answer (score 1):

As P_K says in his answer, the function you are talking about is not a metric. Note that there are no values for $(x,y)$ such that this function takes the value of zero. 
It does not matter if it does or doesn't fulfill the axiom of the triangle inequality.

Comment: question updated I forget to add $d(x,y) = 0$ when $x = y$